It is no longer possible to intuitively close some broad questions
Please correct me if I am wrong, but it is my understanding that the community decided a long while ago (example) that if the question is looking for an answer which is so long it could fill an entire book or section/chapter, then it should be closed for being too broad.
With these questions and situations such as How big is too big for questions? where the stipulated requirements for an acceptable answer is unreasonably large, the ability to do this has gone now, since the old Too broad closure reason has been relabelled to Needs more focus.
This relabelling helps with questions which have more than one question or criteria inside it, and it is more intuitive this way, but it does not help with the situations I have mentioned above.
I propose that we have an additional "community specific reason" of too broad for this purpose.

Duplicate of The newer close reasons don't account for questions that are too general and require lengthy answers.  May also be worth reading “needs more focus”: Significantly different from former “too broad” close reason and Are “too broad” and “needs more focus” abolishable? - I kind of get what he's saying about broad questions just getting broad answers...

Thanks @Arnonweinberg. I have added my 2 cents worth into the first meta discussion you linked.

I think the "needs more focus" close reason still applies in those examples since they also have multiple questions.
I do agree, though, that there are questions that are a problem because they are indeed simply "too broad" because even if they ask concisely they have no limit to their scope. For these I think "needs details or clarity" (the replacement for the old "unclear" reason) can serve the same purpose. I've also shifted to using this close reason on Biology.SE instead of our custom "homework" close reason there in cases where a user is asking for too much of a tutorial ("teach me how photosynthesis works") rather than a specific biology question.
It's also always fine to include a custom comment when voting to close or to add an additional comment explaining the vote using one of the boilerplates. I'm not opposed to adding a custom close reason, but I'm also not sure it's a common enough problem given that most questions will be covered by one of the existing reasons.
